# Korean characters not displaying when pulled from MS Access database using php

Tags: php, asp-classic, utf-8, cjk

I have an Access DB which contains a lot of people with Korean names. I hava a classic ASP site that reads data from the DB quite happily and displays it properly. I am now developing a different site in PHP, but it is unable to display Korean characters. I have written two very simple scripts, one in ASP and one in PHP to work out why.

ASP:

```
<%
Response.CodePage = 65001

Set objLoginConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objLoginConn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
objLoginConn.Open "C:\wwwroot\mydb.mdb"
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

SQL = "SELECT firstname FROM mytable"
rs.Open SQL, objLoginConn, 3, 3

while not rs.EOF
    response.write("<p>"& rs.fields("firstname").value &"</p>")
    rs.movenext
wend
%>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$con = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$con->Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = mydb.mdb");

$SQL = "SELECT firstname FROM mytable";
$rs = $con->execute($SQL);

while (!$rs->EOF) {
    echo "<p>".$rs->Fields("firstname")->value."</p>";
    $rs->movenext();
}
?>
```

The ASP script prints all the names correctly, but the PHP script prints a load of ?'s. If I remove the `Response.CodePage = 65001` bit from the ASP script, it prints ?'s just like PHP.

I then turned my attention to finding a PHP equivilent of `Response.CodePage = 65001` and found things like `header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');` and `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');` but they did not do the job.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is an encoding problem. I had one of those some time ago but do not know how I solved it. Unfortunately there are many places where the encoding can be set. Beginning at the Table, Database, Database-Connection, PHP itself and finally the HTML document. Those `?` usually come from characters that are not allowed in your encoding.

Comment: well both scripts are accessing the same table, so the table and database parts must be ok for the ASP script to work. I have set PHP to utf-8 as stated above to no avail, perhaps i need to set the encoding for the DB connection. no idea how to do that tho!

Comment: I did not use COM yet, but I read something, maybe try: `$con->charSet = 'UTF8';` before Open. I only used MySQL when this problem occured to me and there are some special function to deal with this in MySQL.

Comment: Ok, i have found a solution. I had to set the encoding of the DB connection like so:

`$con = new COM("ADODB.Connection", NULL, 65001);`

where the `65001` is utf-8 i think. Not sure if this is the best way to go, but it works for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i have found a solution. I had to set the encoding of the DB connection like so:

`$con = new COM("ADODB.Connection", NULL, 65001);`

where the `65001` is utf-8 i think. Not sure if this is the best way to go, but it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

$con = new COM ("ADODB.Connection", NULL, CP_UTF8);

will work too.

```
COM::__construct ( string $module_name [, mixed $server_name [, int $codepage [, string $typelib ]]] )

$module_name = "ADODB.Connection"
$server_name = NULL (using default, localmachine)
$codepage = CP_UTF8
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php